# Accessing a field of a class after a lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have a weighted graph with its nodes and edges.

Each node contains a LinkedList called edges that stores the edges of this node. Each edge has an weight and a node (node at the other end).

I already did this:

```
static void removeEdge(Node n1, Node n2)
{
     n1.edges.Remove(n1.edges.First(a => a.node == n2));
     n2.edges.Remove(n2.edges.First(a => a.node == n1));
}
```

I am trying to do an updateEdge method, that would take that same lambda expression and then do this:

```
(a => a.node == n2).weight = otherValue;
```

but I am getting an error. Isn't this allowed? Or am I doing something wrong? From what I've tested the lambda expression seems ok as far as removing the elements, though I'm new at this so I'm pretty lost tbh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what a lambda is. When you say something like

```
...First(x => x.bar == 10)
```

what happens is we generate something like this:

```
static bool M(X x) { return x.bar == 10; }
...
...  First(new Func<X, bool>( M ) )
```

That is, we make a method out of the lambda, and then make a delegate out of the method, and then pass the delegate.

Doing something like

```
(x=>x.bar==10).foo = whatever
```

is morally the same as doing something like M.foo = whatever, where M is a method. Methods don't have properties, so this is always illegal. Similarly, lambdas don't have properties either.  A lambda is just a convenient syntax for a method.

Answer (score 0):

Oooooooh!

I just needed to do this:

```
n1.edges.First(a => a.node == n2).weight = otherValue;
n2.edges.First(a => a.node == n1).weight = otherValue;
```